# webpack 5 display-modules option stopped working

Tags: webpack, webpack-cli

In webpack 4 I was using --display-modules option of webpack-cli. I can also see it in the documentation.
moving to webpack 5, my build started to fail with below error:

```
[webpack-cli] Error: Unknown option '--display-modules'
[webpack-cli] Run 'webpack --help' to see available commands and options
```

After checking webpack 5 documentation I saw that the option was removed but I did not see anything about it in the breaking changes between the versions.

Is there an alternative?

Comment: Same problem here

Answer (score 0):

For Webpack 5, use `stats.modules` (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/#statsmodules) - it tells stats whether to add information about the built modules:

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  stats: {
    modules: true,
  },
};
```